# Prestashop product combination display on product list

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to get available product combination (size) in product list page on each product. Basically there is a image, product name, **available combinations**, price, buy button.

I tried to out put $product object, but it does not have combination variable to it.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

There is function `assignAttributesGroups()` in the `ProductController.php` from where you can get code for size combination.

```
protected function assignAttributesGroups()
{
...
...
...
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'groups' => $groups,
            'colors' => (count($colors)) ? $colors : false,
            'combinations' => $combinations,
            'combinationImages' => $combination_images
        ));
}
```

If you print the value of `groups` you will get desired output. The combinations has been arranged to show dropdown in `product.tpl`(/PRESTASHOP_FOLDER/themes/default-bootstrap/product.tpl) as shown in image [image]

You can take a code from the function mentioned above and run it for every product in the list. You have to create a product object and receive combination through it. And create a drop down for the same.

Comment: yes, but I want to get combinations to show up on category.tpl. Where it outputs all products in category. On product card to show all avaiable to buy combinations. So I guess it has to do sometjhing with category controller

Comment: Yes you have to write code in category controller. Just read the function deeply and try to use such code to make your function to fetch combination. Once all combination is fetched you can use that. Please note that in Product controller all the combination are fetched for that particular product which is open on browser and for which product controller ran so `$this->product` used but to show on category page you have to create an object of Product.